# Spring Cloud Data Flow java DSL: get logs for stream components

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using SCDF 2.5.1 deployed locally via docker-compose and my software sends commands to the SCDF server via the java DSL.

Let's say I create a stream such that

```
file > :queue
:queue > ftp
```

where `file` and `ftp` are docker deployed apps.

My question is, how can I get the logs for `file` and `ftp`?

So far the closest thing I've come up with is

```
Map<String, String> attributes = scdf.runtimeOperations().streamStatus(streamName).getContent()
                .stream().flatMap(stream -> stream.getApplications().getContent().stream()
                        .filter(app -> app.getName().equals(appName))
                        .flatMap(appStatus -> appStatus.getInstances().getContent().stream()
                                .map(AppInstanceStatusResource::getAttributes)))
                .findFirst().orElse(Collections.emptyMap());

String logLocation = attributes.get("stdout")
```

and then mounting `logLocation` and reading it as a file.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java DSL (and subsequently the SCDF REST client) doesn't have `log` retrieval operation as part of it's REST operations. There is an [REST endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-stream-logs) you can hit the SCDF server to get the logs of stream.

If you would like to contribute, you can submit a proposal/PR here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pulls

Comment: Thank  you  for your reply. From the docs you sent I see there is a section ["Get the logs of a specific application from the stream"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-stream-logs-by-app-name). I think that has what I want, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll see about submitting a PR to get it called via java DSL